# Obtaining parameters passed with zend php _forward

Tags: php, zend-framework

A simple question really.
I am using the _forward function in the Zend Php Framework.

$this->_forward('formview', null, null, array('test'=>'penu'));

So Im forwarding to the formview action with the same controller with the paramater test = 'penu'

However how do obtain this value when I am in the action which I am forwarded to.

Answer (score 8):

```
$test=$this->getRequest()->getParam('test');
```

Answer (score 3):

Or $this->_getParam('test')